# ADF - SSIS Execution Package Error 114 - Ssis Operation failed with unexpected operation status : Running

Tags: azure, ssis, azure-data-factory

When running an SSIS package in ADF that takes > +/- 15 minutes, I always get an error message inside ADF (see screenshot).The bizarre thing is that when I look at the execution report itself in the integration services catalog, the status is still on running and eventually will end in succeeded (see screenshot).

Anyone experienced the same? It is frustrating as I can't complete a whole pipeline because of this error.

FYI, the data is coming from a SQL Managed Instance. Region: West-Europe.

The screenshots can also be found on via these two URL's in case they don't show properly inside this question:
https://ibb.co/gufVpp
https://ibb.co/dupqpp

Many thanks in advance!

[ADF error 114 message][Succeeded in Execution report]

Answer (score 0):

Yes we're experiencing the same thing. Very frustrating.
There is a timeout property in the json 'policy' section, but it looks like it's ignored.
I believe you can get around this by executing SSIS using a stored proc instead of Execute SSIS, but not tried it yet.

Comment: Microsoft are aware of the issue, and are currently working on a fix

Comment: Fair play to Microsoft, that was a quick turnaround. This is now fixed and deployed

Comment: Hi Alex, 

It seems to be fixed indeed! Anyway, thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

So I finally got Microsoft sort this out for me.

The problem is that when the first task flow runs in the package, the second one starts as well although it will not show that the 2nd task is running. Because the 2nd task is expecting to use the output from the 1st task, an error occurs.

This is a known issue at Microsoft. They have sorted this out for me, it appears there isn't much you can do on your side to sort this out. Log a ticket with Microsoft instead.

Comment: Hi Lesia, 

We logged a ticket already. They admitted it is a bug on their side and we are currently waiting for official communication that it is fixed.